# How can I launch an email from a website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, email, outlook

I am developing a seat plan website.  When a desk is clicked I get the info of the person sitting at the desk fine (name,phone,email).  Now I want to have a email button beside the persons email address (similar to what lync 2011 had if anyone has seen it).  On click off the button I would like to launch a new email in outlook and have the persons email address in the To field.

My solution is being developed in Visual Studio 2010, and uses C#, ASP, XML and Javascript/JQuery/JSON.

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this - any links or sample source would be great.

Comment: If Outlook is your default Mail client, why not use a simple mailto:you@example.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mailto:email@address.com`

Put that in a link. and viola you are good ^_^

Example:

```
<a href="mailto:harry@hogwarts.edu">Email Harry</a>
```

See example here with a button (as described in comments below): 
 http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/DqYKw

Comment: This does not work reliably.  It rarely works with anyone who uses webmail (Gmail, Yahoo mail, Hotmail, etc...)

Comment: @jfriend00 if you set up gmail correctly it works fine and dandy ^_^

Comment: KOL stated that, "On click off the button I would like to launch a new email in outlook and have the persons email address in the To field." So this will work fine for his purposes

Comment: so if my button is <button type="button">Email</button> - would i put a value tag on this?

Comment: @Neal - only if you install special software on your computer to make gmail work properly and then only on that computer.  Most people do not have that software installed on every computer they access their account from.  Like I said, "if you want it to work reliably for users of webmail, you can't do it this way".

Comment: @KOL surround the `button` with the `<a>` tag.

Comment: @jfriend00 no installation needed ^_^

Comment: @Neal, if you have no Google plugins installed, try a mailto: link in IE, Safari, Firefox, etc...  It won't know you even have a gmail account.  That knowledge isn't built into the browser so the only way it can go to your gmail account is if there is some kind of external software that links the browser to your gmail account.

Comment: @Neal - i used you link above so now my code for the button is as follows - <a href="mailto:testy@test.com"><button type="button">Email</button></a> The button is there when I click each persons details when I run my solution is Visual Studio but when I click it nothing happens....

Comment: @KOL try in a real browser ^_^

Comment: @Neal - when I run in VS - it opens it in IE - this is what I need it to run in as all my users will only be using IE.

Comment: Check my link. if that works in IE, then your code should also work in IE

Comment: @Neal - nah it doesnt work in IE for me.  Though I have chrome installed on my machine and it works on it :(

Comment: @KOL works fine in IE for me. you might want to ask another question somewhere as to why it does not work for you.

Comment: @Neal and just incase anyone else comes across this - link explains why this wasnt working - I am using Windows 7 and IE8 - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/1c8028e6-9238-46e7-8ec3-f93f03ee67a8/

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as using a mailto link:

```
<a href="mailto:nospam@nospam.com">Email!</a>
```

If you need more details, check out this [beginner's tutorial from about.com](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa041700b.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you want is when somebody clicks the link/button they have  a new E-Mail from outlook come up with the E-Mail in the to bar and they just type their message and hit send ? If so most if not all browsers recognize the `mailto:` protocol.

So if you make a link with `<a href="mailto:myemail@example.com">Mail me</a>` . The browser will open up a new message screen addressed to mailto:myemail@example.com.

Just watched out for bots that can crawl this information and use them for spam ....

Answer (score 0):

you meant to use [mailto Protoco](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)l  / [MailTo   Syntax](http://zoomquiet.org/res/scrapbook/ZqSKM/data/20100419224556/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to link it to your default mail composer? You could use html anchor like this

```
<a href='mailto:email@address.com'>Email</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.